# Imbed a control in webpage to get PDF selection area width/height & X,Y coordinates

Tags: asp.net, coordinates, pdf-viewer

I am looking to add an option in a web page, which could tell the X/Y coordinates, width and height of the selection area on PDF page. User can select any area (using left-click select) in the PDF visible in web page through PDFViewer.

I would appreciate if someone can point out any plugin, PDF viewer etc. supporting this feature in .NET web page.

Comment: I assume PDF.js can do this, but someone else would have to provide that answer. Why is selecting an area of a page important? What happens after the area is selected?

Comment: One of the few use cases I have is to apply a ZONE using these coordinate for optical mark recognition or data redaction etc. I'll look into PDF.js and update if it serves the purpose. Thank you @Ryan